# Combs on a large set doesn't compute Haskell

Tags: haskell, subset, binomial-coefficients

I'm writing a combs function in haskell
what it needs to do is, when I provide it with a deck of cards, give me every combination of hands possible from that deck of size x

This is the relevant code

```
combs :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combs 0 _      = [[ ]]
combs i (x:xs) =  (filter (isLength i) y)
            where y = subs (x:xs)
combs _ _      = [ ]

isLength :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
isLength i x
        | length x == i = True
        | otherwise     = False

subs :: [a] -> [[a]]
subs [ ] = [[ ]]
subs (x : xs) = map (x:) ys ++ ys
            where ys = subs xs
```

However, when I ask it to compute a combs 5 [1..52], e.g. a hand of 5 out of a full deck, it does not provide a result, and keeps running for a really long time
Does anyone know what the problem is and how to speed up this algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract `i` items from `x:xs` you can proceed in two ways:

- you keep the `x`, and extract only `i-1` elements from `xs`
- you discard `x`, and extract all the `i` elements from `xs`

Hence, a solution is:

```
comb :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
comb 0 _      = [[]]  -- only the empty list has 0 elements
comb _ []     = []    -- can not extract > 0 elements from []
comb i (x:xs) = [ x:ys | ys <- comb (i-1) xs ]  -- keep x case
                ++ comb i xs                    -- discard x case
```

By the way, the above code also "proves" a well-known recursive formula for the binomial coefficients. You might already have met this formula if you attended a calculus class.
Letting `B(k,n) = length (comb k [1..n])`, we have

```
B(k+1,n+1) == B(k,n) + B(k+1,n)
```

which is just a direct consequence of the last line of the code above.

Comment: The same problem occurs as in Carsten's solution, as is a reserved keyword, and I get a parse error on input |  
Also, I am not trying to extract i elements from x:xs, I am trying to generate all the possible combinations C(i,x:xs), e.g. "how many different hands of 5 can I pull out of a deck of 52 cards" and then generate every single possible hand

Comment: @LordofTurtles Wouldn't `comb 5 allCards` solve that? It should extract all the possible hands, ignoring order.

Comment: Oh wait, your code does exactly what I had in mind, great!
I am not particularly good at list comprehensions at this point, so I was confused

Answer (score 3):

Right now it's a bit hard to see what you are trying to do - but I guess the problems you have is that you gonna filter and map a lot.

I think a simple way to get what you need is this:

```
module Combinations where

import Data.List (delete)

combs :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combs 0 _ = [[]]
combs i xs = [ y:ys | y <- xs, ys <- combs (i-1) (delete y xs) ]
```

which uses `delete` from `Data.List`

It should be lazy enough to find you combinations quick - of course all will take a while ;)

```
λ> take 5 $ combs 5 [1..52]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,6],[1,2,3,4,7],[1,2,3,4,8],[1,2,3,4,9]]
```

#### how does it work

it's one of those recursive combinatorial algorithm that works by selecting a first card `y` from all the cards `xs`, and then recursivley get`s the rest of the hand`ys`from the deck without the selected card`delete a xs`and then putting it back together`y:ys` inside the list-monad (here using list-comprehensions).

BTW: ther are 311,875,200 such decks ;)

#### version without list-comprehensions

here is a version without comprehensions in case your system has issues here:

```
combs :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combs 0 _ = [[]]
combs i xs = do
  y <- xs
  ys <- combs (i-1) (delete y xs)
  return $ y:ys
```

#### version that will remove permutations

this one uses `Ord` to get *sort* the items in ascending order and in doing so removing duplciates in respect to permutaion - for this to work `xs` is expected to be pre-sorted!

**Note** chi's version is working with fewer constraints and might be more preformant too - but I thougt this is nice and readable and goes well with the version before so maybe it's of interest to you.

I know it's not a thing often done in Haskell/FP where you strife for the most general and abstract cases but I come form an environment where most strive for readability and understanding (coding for the programmer not only for the compiler) - so be gentle ;)

```
combs' :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combs' 0 _  = [[]]
combs' i xs = [ y:ys | y <- xs, ys <- combs' (i-1) (filter (> y) xs) ]
```

Comment: Two questions: Since "as" is a reserved keyword, should it not be y:ys? and when I copy your code to try it out, I get a parse error on input |

Comment: @LordofTurtles I added a module definition as well - do you get errors if you copy this to some .hs file and load it in ghci still?

Comment: @LordofTurtles - btw: where do you put it? GHCi? - or is this some other Haskell system?

Comment: It now creates a parse error in input module, oddly enough
I am using GHCi, yes

Perhaps related, above where I'm putting combs is this statement:
instance Ord Hand where
    x `compare` y = (handCategory x) `compare` (handCategory y)

Comment: @LordofTurtles sorry to say but I think your installation might be glitched - can you put your code on a GIST or add it to your question so I can have a look? Maybe you have some tabs in there (?)

Comment: I apologize, I made an error and forgot to comment out a section of my combs code, leading to the parse error
Your code works fine, except that it provides too much output, combs 4 [1,2,3,4] should only give [[1,2,3,4]] as output, but it also includes the other 3 permutations of that set, any way to filter those out easily?

Comment: you mean the permutations of [1,2,3,4]? well yes - I add it - but it will basically be the version chi gave you